# SQL Shortel Abandoned Calls Query

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, case, shoretel

I am tring to query a table and it doesnt seem to be working. can anyone assist?

```
SELECT     ExitReason AS CallsAbandoned
FROM         queuecall
WHERE     (ExitReason = 7) THEN
                  (ExitReason = 1 ELSE
                  (ExitReason = 0)))
```

The deninition or outcome i am looking for is:

```
if {ExitReason} = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

I am not sure how complete the right query.

Thanks,
Arron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ExitReason = 7 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END AS CallsAbandoned 
FROM queuecall
```

Or if you are wanting a count of the result of the CASE then try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ExitReason = 7 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END) AS CallsAbandoned 
FROM queuecall
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT IF(EXITREASON = 7, 1, 0) AS CallsAbandoned 
FROM   QUEUECALL
```

[SQL FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a1d/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a1d/1)

Comment: Guys. This Query did not work for me. The above query linger provided was a validated query for me. I Didnt what to leave you guys hanging.

Comment: Yes, Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Are you using Mysql? Which version

Comment: I am using SQL2012 and Navicat for MySQL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42623/discussion-between-ramesh-and-arronrobles)